# Como alinhar uma foto, no centro da página?

Tags: html, css

Eu sei que pra alinhar um texto se usa o `text-align: center`.

Mas e pra alinhar uma foto que tem um link nela? Eu fiz uns testes aqui com uns comandos que eu n conheço tipo o `align-content`, pra ver se dava certo, mas n deu. Tenho duas perguntas.

1° Como alinha uma foto que tenha um link dentro, no centro da página?

2° Essa linha está certa? Para posteriormente colocar o código de alinhamento dentro dela.

```
 .imagem {}
```

Edit: Eu tentei colocar o `margin:auto`, na `div` da imagem, mas n funcionou, n fez alteração alguma.

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>sas</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sasi.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="imagem">

        <a href="#"><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/l6JAkhvfxbP61_FWN92j4ulDMXJNH3HT1DR6xrE7MtwW-2AxpZl_WLnBzTpWhCuYkbHihgBQ=w640-h400-e365" width="50%" height="50%"></a>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Css:

```
.imagem {
    margin:auto; //aplica margem aos quatro lados
    width:200px;
}
```

Comment: Se a div não tiver um tamanho definido ela será 100% da pagina verticalmente ou 100% da outra div, mas como você não apresentou o código completo não é possível saber o que está causando o problema

Comment: @MarkVaaz Eu coloquei o seu codigo nesse arquivo, realmente n funcionou o margin: center. Eu alterei o tamanho da imagem de 100% para 50%, pq em 100% a imagem ficava do tamanho da tela, e n dava pra saber se o codigo pra centralizala no meio da pagina teria dado certo.

Comment: @MarkVaaz Exatamente.

Comment: `sasi` é o arquivo css? não seria `sasi.css`?  e não existe margin center, para centralizar horizontalmente se usa `margin:auto;` ou `margin:10px auto;` 10px para definir margem de 10px verticalmente, não precisa ser necessariamente 10px, você pode definir a quantidade que preferir

Comment: @MarkVaaz Sim, eu esqueci de colocar o .css. Eu coloquei agr, mas n mudou nada. É o certo é margin: auto, como vc disse, eu so me confudi na hora que escrevi o comentario. Esse codigo que colei ai, vc testou pra ver se centralizava no meio?

Comment: alterei a resposta e coloquei o seu `HTML`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Você pode colocar a imagem dentro de uma `div` definir uma classe
  para essa `div` e adicionar `margin:0 auto` ao `css` para alinhar a
  imagem no centro da pagina ou de uma outra `div`.

> [Saiba mais sobre `margin` aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/margin)

### Exemplo:

```css
.imagem {
    margin:0 auto; /* margem vertical definida como 0 e horizontal automática */
    width:200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>sas</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sasi.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="imagem">

        <a href="#"><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/l6JAkhvfxbP61_FWN92j4ulDMXJNH3HT1DR6xrE7MtwW-2AxpZl_WLnBzTpWhCuYkbHihgBQ=w640-h400-e365" width="100%"></a>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

### Exemplo com `css` diretamente no `HTML`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>sas</title>
<style type="text/css">
.imagem {
    margin:0 auto; /* margem vertical definida como 0 e horizontal automática */
    width:200px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="imagem">

        <a href="#"><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/l6JAkhvfxbP61_FWN92j4ulDMXJNH3HT1DR6xrE7MtwW-2AxpZl_WLnBzTpWhCuYkbHihgBQ=w640-h400-e365" width="100%"></a>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

O `0` em `margin:0 auto;` representa o valor vertical, você pode adicionar `50px` para definir o valor verticalmente, ou quantos pixels for necessário.

Exemplo de margem definindo diferentes tamanhos para cada lado:

`margin: 25px 50px 75px 100px;`

- superior está como: *25px*
- direita está como: *50px*
- inferior está como: *75px*
- esquerda está como: *100px*

> Note que se a `div` não tiver um tamanho definido o valor dela verticalmente será de 100% da pagina ou de um outro elemento pai, caso seja 100% não é possível centralizar usando `margin`.

Comment: Eu conheço e uso a propriedade magin, o básico pelo menos. Eu n tenho ctz se foi vc que n entendeu direito, ou se foi eu. Eu consigo alinha a foto no centro da página, usando o margin, mas pra isso eu preciso fazer certas contas matematicas, não que isso seja um problema, mas eu queria saber se tem como simplificar isso. Entao, eu estava querendo saber se tem como alinhar automaticamente uma imagem no centro da página, tipo o text-align. Eu tentei usar o margin: 0 auto; e margin; auto, como vc disse, mas n funcionou, a imagem so sai do lugar depois que eu coloco algum valor dentro do margin.

Comment: Como você pode ver no snippet e os detalhes da resposta, o `margin:0 auto;` funciona perfeitamente, você está fazendo algo de errado no seu código...

Comment: @DiogenesSilva atualizei a resposta com o `css` no `HTML`

Comment: Eu consegui, a imagem n estava centralizando por causa disso "//aplica margem aos quatro lados" essa frase estava nessa linha .imagem {
    margin: 0 auto; //aplica margem aos quatro lados. Obriago pela ajuda!
    width:200px;
}

Comment: você estava usando o código desatualizado... eu ja tinha atualizado a resposta